# Java singleton pattern outputs tow same object in multithreading?

Tags: java, singleton

```
public class Foo {

    private static  Foo foo;
    private Foo(){}
    public static Foo getInstance(){
        if (foo==null){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            foo = new Foo();
            System.out.println(foo+"----"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
        return foo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                Foo foo1 = Foo.getInstance();
            }
        },"thread1");

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Foo foo2 = Foo.getInstance();
            }
        },"thread2");
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    }
}
```

I just only want to simulate these code is unsafe in multi-threading environment,but it's always output two same object like :

```
Foo@24c21495----thread1
Foo@24c21495----thread2
```

or

```
Foo@3d4b7453----thread1
Foo@3d4b7453----thread2

...
```

why?

Comment: Because foo is static

Comment: On my machine it returned different object in the first run. Try more runs.

Comment: If you try it more it will produce different object.

Comment: I think the call `System.out.println(foo+"----"+Thread.currentThread().getName())` is slow enough to not let both the threads display their own results. Because from the output we can tell that both the threads are entering the if block, which basically means both are constructing new objects. But while printing both are printing the latest. I might want to try printing a `Foo temp` instead of `foo`.

Comment: You might want to try `Foo temp = new Foo(); foo = temp;` and print `temp` instead of `foo`. This should display the expected output, IMO, if (some tricky) re-ording doesn't mess it up.

Comment: I suggest you try just `enum Foo { INSTANCE: ` and you will find you can only have one value and it is *much* simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there are two combined reasons here:

- The very first thing you print is the result. All kinds of code is probably being JIT-compiled here and potentially other resources initialized. I believe this is acting as an inherent synchronization point, effectively.
- Your sleep is very short, and uniform, which doesn't help.

Basically, I believe both threads are creating new instances and then both are displaying results - and unless you're "lucky", both threads are seeing the results of whichever thread performs the assignment second.

If you just add:

```
System.out.println("Starting");
```

to the very start of `main`, you'll *sometimes* see different output. If you also change your sleep to:

```
Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 100));
```

... then you're much more likely to see it. Basically, you want one thread to go through the whole of "sleep, initialize, print" while the other thread is sleeping.

Another option is to simply add a print statement to the constructor: even if both threads show the same object in your current diagnostic location, you'll still see two instances being constructed, which demonstrates that the code is unsafe.

Comment: If both threads sleep for the same amount of time, this might not produce the same out come.

Comment: +1. Getting two different instances or `Foo` is purely at the mercy of _chance_ and hence to _increase_ that chance, what you suggest makes sense. [Another way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) would be to make sure (at least in theory and as far as possible) thread reach a certain execution point at the same time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, it *could* still produce the undesired outcome - but it will greatly improve the chances of seeing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `sleep(1)` only sleeps for 1 millisecond. By the time the 2nd thread hits `getInstance` your `foo` has already been initialized.

What you probably want is to call a `synchronized` init function which checks if `foo` is null before setting it. No need to sleep at all. It will still output the same, but will be a thread safe initializer.

Example:

```
public static Foo getInstance () {
  if( foo == null )
    initFoo();
  return foo;
}

private static synchronized void initFoo () {
  if( foo == null )
    foo = new Foo();
}
```

Comment: My experience diagnosing this suggests your first sentence is incorrect, at least on my machine. Two instances *are* being created - but by the time the results are *printed*, the two threads are sufficiently "in sync" that they're both printing the same value. And the OP isn't trying to come up with thread-safe initialization (there are simpler ways of doing that) - he's trying to prove that the current code is *unsafe*.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, both outcomes are possible. But there would have to be better debugging to be sure which happened. And who knows if the same thing that happens on my machine happens on yours.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Within a single `classloader`, `static fields` are always shared.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the question. The code provided isn't thread-safe: it's meant to be a singleton, and it isn't due to a lack of any sort of synchronization.

Comment: True, nevertheless with the above setup it could be the case that the two threads get two different instances of Foo: just increase the sleep time sufficiently. However, if this is the intention this is definitely not a good way of achiving it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think the question was specific enough for any of us to know with certainty exactly what was being asked.

Comment: @Shadow Creeper: I think it's pretty clear, personally: "I just only want to simulate these code is unsafe in multi-threading environment"

Comment: @JonSkeet What language do you speak natively? As a native English speaker, I'm not sure what is being asked. I can guess, but I have no guarantee that my guess is correct.

Comment: @ShadowCreeper: I'm a native English speaker, although I doubt that the OP is. It seems clear to me: the OP has code which he knows is not thread-safe, and he's introduced a sleep and diagnostics in order to *show* that it's not thread-safe... but he was still seeing results as if it *were* thread-safe, contrary to his expectation and intention. I'm not going to claim any sort of "guarantee" about that interpretation, but it doesn't seem particularly unclear to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet So with getInstance() mwthod OP wants to get two different references of a single object ??

Comment: @Baadshah: The OP wants to *demonstrate* that using this unsynchronized implementation, two separate instances can be created, contrary to the requirement of a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "singleton per thread" than you might want to look at ThreadLocal [1]. Then you also do not have to take care of properly synchronizing calls to getInstance.

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html